# Unable to open MATLAB using terminal in fedora 20

Tags: matlab

I have been using matlab in fedora 20, my laptop does not go into sleep mode, but my laptop got accidentally closed and after that it is not running. I usually use
cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin and then ./matlab

I have tried killing the process id also. But even then matlab is not working. Please help. What do I do now?

Comment: Try restarting the computer..

Comment: I HAVE TRIED THAT.. STILL NOT WORKING..

Comment: OK YOU CAN STOP SCREAMING NOW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this steps:

```
If you are having trouble starting MATLAB on a UNIX-based system and you are not receiving license manager related errors, your start up problems may be resolved by performing the following steps:

Step #1:

=========

Remove your preferences directory, so that it can be recreated cleanly:

1. Open the Terminal Application (usually found in Applications or Utilities).

2. In the terminal window and run the following commands:

cd ~/.matlab

3. Once in the .matlab folder, delete the folder for the version of MATLAB you have. For example, if you have R2008a, run the command:

rm -rf R2008a

4. Once cleared, restart MATLAB. The preferences should be recreated.

If the above solution does not help, run the step below and contact MathWorks Technical Support if the steps fail:

Step #2:

=========

Try running MATLAB with SELinux disabled. SELinux may prevent MATLAB from starting. To temporarily disable it, run the following command as root:

/usr/sbin/setenforce 0
(/usr/sbin/setenforce 1 will turn SELinux back on)

Once disabled, try MATLAB again. If it works, see the Related Solution at the bottom of the page:

"Why do I receive errors relating to the file "libmwlapack" when starting MATLAB

R14SP3 or higher on Linux?"

Step #3:

=========

If you see an error about "Locking assertion failure" or the error:

 MATLAB: xcb_xlib.c:52: xcb_xlib_unlock:Assertion `c->xlib.lock' failed.
 Abort 
a Java bug may be causing the issue. In that case see the Bug Report here:

http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/details.html?rp=460827

Step #4:

=========

Open MATLAB with the Desktop and Java options Disabled:

1. From the terminal, type the following:

      cd $MATLABROOT/bin/ (Where $MATLABROOT is the path to your root MATLAB directory)
      Note: for example cd /usr/local/MATLAB72/bin/
2. Type ./matlab -nodesktop

3. If MATLAB starts using the -nodesktop flag, type "desktop" in the MATLAB command window and send me the output.

If MATLAB will not start in the -nodesktop mode, try the following:

1. From the terminal, type the following:

      cd $MATLABROOT/bin/ (Where $MATLABROOT is the path to your root MATLAB directory)
      Note: for example cd /usr/local/MATLAB72/bin/
2. Type ./matlab -nojvm

3. Let me know if MATLAB starts in this mode.

Step #5:

========

If the above solutions do not work, be sure that there are no files conflicting on your MATLAB path. To verify that your work files and/or startup.m files are not conflicting with this MATLAB installation, perform the following steps:

1. Create folder called /usr/local/MATLAB_work/

2. Move all of your work files (from the folder $MATLABROOT/work/) into this new folder.

3. Start MATLAB again to see if the problem still occurs.

4. If this resolves the problem, one of your work files is likely conflicting with your MATLAB installation.

You must make sure none of your work files have the same name as an existing MATLAB function. You will need to determine which files cause this error before moving your work files back into your MATLAB directory.
```

With reference to: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98599-why-will-matlab-not-start-up-properly-on-my-linux-or-unix-based-system